# Mmimic MS Access in python for data entry and connect the resulting table with other tables

Tags: python, forms, input

Could anybody tell me if I am on the right path if want to mimic MS Access in python by using dictionaries? I want to build a input form like the ones in for example Microsoft Access. I already build the code below which worked fine but then i found out that in dictionaries usually there is only one value per key. 
So now I wonder what the preferable option is, maybe an array in numpy or maybe use lists as a value in the dictionary?

After building the datatable I would like to be able to connect it with other tables and do calculations with it just like in MS Access but I guess I can code that myself.

```
my_dict = dict()
value=0
while value != "q":
     print (my_dict)
     editkey = input("choose key to edit or q to quit: ")
     if editkey in my_dict.keys():
         print ("already existing key with value: ")
         print (my_dict[editkey])
         newvalueyn=input("new value y/n?: ")
         if newvalueyn == "y":
             value=input("new value: ")
             my_dict[editkey] = value
         else:
             print("no change")
     else:
         value=input("new value: ")
         my_dict[editkey] = value
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand how dicts relates to ms access, 'entry form' and databases. Just a hint though: dicts _always_ hold a single value per key indeed - that's part of the definition of a dict actually - but this value can be a `list`, `set`, `dict` or whatever.

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear on that: I want to write python code that mimics MS Access for data entry and connect the resulting table with other tables. Basically i want to write a python version of MS Access.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I still don't understand how this relates to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction Bruno, I changed the question, i hope its more clear now

Comment: I am afraid not. MS Access is composed of a (more or less) SQL database and a lot of components to define DB schemas,  build listings and forms and reports etc, plus add some "custom" code hence making it a kind of a development environment. How does this relate to dicts and a piece of command line script ? If you want to build a database / forms editor, the first thing to do is to use a database and some GUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

Im not there yet but one step at a time

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([7, 8, 9])
index = np.array([0, 1, 2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['project', 'start', 'end'], index=index)
df2.loc[0:1] = [list(s1), list(s2)]
our_list = [] # create empty list
while objectnr != "q": 
    objectnr = int(input('objectnr or q: '))
    print(df2.loc[objectnr])
    newvalueyn=input("new value y/n?: ")
    if newvalueyn == "y":
        first_num = int(input('Enter first number: '))
        second_num = int(input('Enter second number: '))
        third_num = int(input('Enter third number: '))
        our_list.append(first_num)
        our_list.append(second_num)
        our_list.append(third_num)
        df2.loc[objectnr] = np.asarray(our_list)
        print(df2)
    else:
        print(df2)
```